# How to get all proporties from ng-options in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm populating a dropdown list from an object. I want to set the related model value as binded object's "text". But also I have to send a parameter (binded object's value) for a function. I can do this. But Model's value is getting all the object. I want only get the object's Text.

```js
var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    "Text": "75.000",
    "Value": 1
  }, {
    "Text": "100.000",
    "Value": 2
  }, {
    "Text": "150.000",
    "Value": 3
  }, {
    "Text": "250.000",
    "Value": 4
  }];
  $scope.GetVal = function(val) {
    alert(val);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">

  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="item as item.Text for item in list" ng-change="GetVal(model.Value)">

  </select>


  <pre>
 my model: {{model}}
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

My Codes as seen below. Can you help please?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need..

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding I have updated the cod  please check and let me know if this is what u need.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">

  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="item as item.Text for item in list" ng-change="GetVal(model)">
   <option value= "" disabled="">select value</option>
  </select>


  <pre>
 my model: {{model.Text}}
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

// Code goes here

```
   var app = angular.module("App", []);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope) {
  $scope.list = [{
    "Text": "75.000",
    "Value": 1
  }, {
    "Text": "100.000",
    "Value": 2
  }, {
    "Text": "150.000",
    "Value": 3
  }, {
    "Text": "250.000",
    "Value": 4
  }];
  $scope.GetVal = function(val) {
    alert(val.Value);
  };
});
```

Comment: Hi. First of all, sorry for my bad English. I just want to set my model's value as clicked option's TEXT, and send a parameter with GetVal function selected option's VALUE. All I need is this. Is that clear?

Comment: @BasarSen check this answer will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Basar,

You will need to change the ng-repeat as below

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">

  <select ng-model="model" ng-options="item as item.Value for item in list" ng-change="GetVal(model)">
   <option value= "" disabled="">select value</option>
  </select>


  <pre>
 my model: {{model.Value}}
  </pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes but this time, my model returns an object like this {"Text":"100.000","Value":2}. I want to return it only like 100.000

Comment: Are you sure? PLease check this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/GOeVC0lEueHXQ41P60OA?p=preview

Comment: You wrote {{model.Value}}. I cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

sen,

Do you wish to bind only `Text` to your `model`? or `Text` and `Value` both?

If you only wish to bind Text, please check updated [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/MQ5Chru8Cf59SOxqUXsd?p=preview).

I know, this is an old question.

Comment: I don't know why it does not take `@basar-sen` !